# Refresh of cascading panels

Tags: xpages, javabeans

Is have a problem with a refresh of the content on a cascading panel, that contains objects connected to the object of the primary panel? Primary panel has data source of "Invoice" (a managed bean) and the cascaded panel has the content of "Invoice.getAllInvoiceItems()" a List of objects (InvoiceItem).

**Primary Panel (I'm loading the bean in beforePageLoad event, not in the primary panel):**

```
 <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:on="http://www.openntf.org/domino/xsp"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:Invoice.pageInit();}]]>        
    </xp:this.beforePageLoad>
  <xp:panel id="mainpanel" rendered="#{javascript:Invoice.getValid();}"
        readonly="#{javascript:Invoice.readOnly;}">
```

**Cascaded Panel:**

```
<xp:panel id="RepeatInvoiceItems">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xe:objectData var="invoiceItem"
            createObject="#{javascript:Invoice.getAllInvoiceItems()}">
        </xe:objectData>
    </xp:this.data>
```

I configured Invoice as managed bean in the **Faces-config**, but InvoiceItem not, because I don't think that's necessary...

```
   <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>Invoice</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-bean-class>com.kitc.controller.ControllerInvoice</managed-bean-class>
   </managed-bean>
```

My problem is, when I create a new InvoiceItem the panel containing the InvoiceItems does not refresh, but the Panel containing the Invoice does (Proof method Invoice.getTotalPrice() returns the calculated value of all (including the new) InvoiceItems).

Comment: May be the ObjectData is been cached. Why using an objectData, you can bind Invoice.getAllInvoiceItems() directly to a repeatControl

Comment: Why is it cached if I do full refresh?

Comment: because it your bean is viewscoped.... I did not have used ObjectData before, so it was only a suggestion

Comment: Well actually binding the data directly to the repeat control helped to refresh the repeat control. I also tried to set scope of the objectData to `scope="view"` which doesn't help

Comment: may be you should skip the ObjectData then and bind a new invoiceItem to a property of your bean

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that now... Could you write an answer to complete this thread and I will mark your answer as correct....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why using an objectData, you can bind Invoice.getAllInvoiceItems() directly to a repeatControl
And bind a new invoiceItem to a property of your bean

Comment: If somebody else is using this answer we should mention that at the current time on Server Domino 9.0.1 FP5 + extension library and ODA the attribute `scope="view"` on ObjectData does not have the effect you would hope for, if any